# When using `track by $index` with filter I am getting error. how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a bad array values as string. it has the duplicate values in it. i would like to remove the unwanted spaces and numbers from the array string. so i am cleaning all using filter.

the issue is , when i use filter alone, i am getting error for `duplicates` if i remove that, my filter is not working.

how to handle this scenario?

here is my code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

arr=[
  "1. Completion of Site mobilization \n2. Erection of Tower cranes 2, 4 & 5\n3. Facade dismantling  (Grey ACP between Gates 19, 23 & 24;  Steel Louvers between Gates 2 & 3)                                                                       \n4. Excavation for Foundation (AHU Corridor,  Foundation Area 1, 2  &3, External Buildings)\n5. Civil Works on East Expansion for foundation  (F50, F52, F55, F57, F94)\n6. West Stand Roof catwalks dismantling completed 100 %\n7. Assembly/Erection of temporary towers for Lighting Arch \n    dismantling\n8. Score Board dismantling\n9. Completion of Site mobilization 10. Erection of Tower cranes 2, 4 & 5\n11. Facade dismantling  (Grey ACP between Gates 19, 23 & 24;  Steel Louvers between Gates 2 & 3)                                                                       \n12. Excavation for Foundation (AHU Corridor,  Foundation Area 1, 2  &3, External Buildings)\n13. Civil Works on East Expansion for foundation  (F50, F52, F55, F57, F94)14. West Stand Roof catwalks dismantling completed 100 %\n15. Assembly/Erection of temporary towers for Lighting Arch \n    dismantling\n16. Score Board dismantling",
  "",
  ""
]


myApp.controller('main', function($scope){

    $scope.arrays = arr;

});

angular.module("myApp")
.filter("string2array", 

    function () {

        return function ( value ) {

            if(!value) return;

            return value.filter(Boolean).join('\n').replace(/^\d+\.\s+/gm, '').split('\n');

        }

});
```

here is my js try :[Js Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1eksL1em/)

here is `angularjs` integration which makes issue for me

[angualrjs demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zonnn39g/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filters are applied to the `arrays` so you just need to do..

```
<li ng-repeat="array in arrays | string2array track by $index">
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zonnn39g/2/)

Comment: filters can use any input depending on use case ... in this case OP wants to filter array

Comment: @charlietfl I talked about OP's case specifically here.. In general JS arrays are used in `ngRepeat` and If I recall correctly those are the only objects supported natively.. Others need some filter/modification to convert it to arrays to use them

Comment: was only commenting on your general statement that `filters are applied to arrays`. Can pass anything to a filter as long as it is appropriate for use case

Comment: Yeah thanks for the heads up :).. But I only highlighted the OPs use case here.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a filter ? If I understood properly, you need to split your string into an array and then work on it. So, try that in your controller and get rid of your filter:

```
$scope.arrays = arr.filter(Boolean).join('\n').replace(/^\d+\.\s+/gm, '').split('\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the filter in wrong place and are trying to filter `$index` which is a number not an array.

Try

```
 <li ng-repeat="array in arrays | string2array track by $index ">{{array }}</li>
```

read ng-repeat` docs regarding order of query syntax